# Looking for alternatives to QuickTime 7 Pro for OS Catalina concerning audio mapping

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, quicktime

I've been using QuickTime 7 Pro (until recently) in order to QC multi-channel ProRes files. Now, I am unable to QC 5.1 plus Stereo Comp files like I use to.

Is there another app out there that will allow audio channel assignments like QuickTime 7 Pro did in its Audio Settings/Show Movie Properties?